# How do I retrieve all directory paths from Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 using Python?

Tags: python, azure

I'm trying to retrive all paths to directories in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 using the approach mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-python). Here's my code:

```
# Connect to account
def initialize_storage_account_ad(storage_account_name, client_id, client_secret, tenant_id):
    
    try:  
        global service_client

        credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)

        service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url="{}://{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format(
            "https", storage_account_name), credential=credential)
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

# List Directory Contents
def list_directory_contents():
    try:
        
        file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="my-file-system")

        paths = file_system_client.get_paths(path="my-directory")

        for path in paths:
            print(path.name + '\n')

    except Exception as e:
     print(e)
```

Using the `FileSystemClient.get_paths` method retrieves paths to both files and directories.

Is there an efficent workaround to retrieve or filter only directory paths?

Please Advise.

Answer (score 0):

`get_paths`
returns a generator to list the paths(could be files or directories) under the specified file system, which also contains properties for each path.

`path.is_directory == True` helps differentiate directories from files.